# Convert Curl to Ajax using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I just want to ask... how can i convert this code:

```
$url='https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/agents';
$username="boom";
$password="baam";
    // chat user
        $ch1 = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output1 = curl_exec($ch1);
        $info1 = curl_getinfo($ch1);
        curl_close($ch1);
        $userinfo = json_decode($output1);
```

to ajax... I want to call the json data automatically... hope you can help mo on this.. thanks..

Comment: where is the js code, what did you try ?

Comment: i think you want this code load automatic? if yes please put this code in a file and call that file using ajax in a particular time interval.

Comment: @madalinivascu the json is on the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $.ajax or $.post to achive this. Below is an example

**in PHP script**

```
<?php
$url='https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/agents';
$username="boom";
$password="baam";
?>
```

**In javacript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Using the core $.ajax() method
    $.ajax({

        // The URL for the request
        url: "<?php echo $url; ?>",

        // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
        data: {
            username: "<?php echo $username; ?>",
            password: "<?php echo $password; ?>"
        },

        // Whether this is a POST or GET request
        type: "POST",

        // The type of data we expect back
        dataType : "json",
    })
      // Code to run if the request succeeds (is done);
      // The response is passed to the function
      .done(function( json ) {
         //Hurray!! here is your json data
         console.log(json.id);
         console.log(json.title);

      })
      // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
      // status codes are passed to the function
      .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
      })
      // Code to run regardless of success or failure;
      .always(function( xhr, status ) {
        alert( "The request is complete!" );
      });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this got but i got an error...
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/agents. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.`